# Linear algebra proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> **Theorem :-** Let $A : X → Y$ be a linear transformation. Then $A$ is
>   invertible if and only if for any right side $\mathbf b ∈ Y$ the equation
>   $$A \mathbf x =\mathbf b$$
>   has a unique solution $\mathbf x ∈ X$.
>
> **Proof :-**
>
> Suppose $$A \mathbf x = \mathbf y$$ has a unique solution $\mathbf x$ for all $\mathbf y \in Y$. Let this unique solution be $B(\mathbf y)$.
>
> We define a transformation $B : Y \to X$, since $B(\mathbf y)$ is defined for all $\mathbf y \in Y$. Now we need to prove that $B$ i a linear transformation.
>
> Let $\mathbf x_1 := B(\mathbf y_1)$ and $\mathbf x_2 := B(\mathbf y_2)$, so $A \mathbf x_1 = \mathbf y_1$ and $A \mathbf x_2 = \mathbf y_2$. Then
>
> $$A(\alpha \mathbf x_1 + \beta \mathbf x_2) = \alpha A (\mathbf x_1) + \beta A (\mathbf x_2) = \alpha \mathbf y_1 + \beta \mathbf y_2$$
>
> Therefore,
>
> $$B(\alpha \mathbf y_1 + \beta \mathbf y_2) = \alpha B (\mathbf y_1) + \beta B (\mathbf y_2).$$

I did not understand why $$A(\alpha \mathbf x_1 + \beta \mathbf x_2) = \alpha A (\mathbf x_1) + \beta A (\mathbf x_2) = \alpha \mathbf y_1 + \beta \mathbf y_2 \tag 1$$ implies $$B(\alpha \mathbf y_1 + \beta \mathbf y_2) = \alpha B (\mathbf y_1) + \beta B (\mathbf y_2)$$ ?

I get $$B(\alpha \mathbf y_1 + \beta \mathbf y_2) = B(\alpha A (\mathbf x_1) + \beta A (\mathbf x_2))$$ if I take $B$ on both sides of second equality in $(1)$ but I can't simplify this further.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $B:Y \to X$ is given by $AB(y) = y$. We have

$$AB(\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2) = \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2 = \alpha AB(y_1)+\beta A B(y_2) = A(\alpha B(y_1)+ \beta B(y_2)).$$

The first equality above is by the definition of $B$. The second equality I am using $ABy_i = y_i$ and on the third one I am using the linearity of $A$.

Notice that $B(\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2)$ and $\alpha B(y_1)+ \beta B(y_2)$ are solution of the equation $Ax=\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2$ and therefore they are equal:
$$B(\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2)=\alpha B(y_1)+ \beta B(y_2).$$

Comment: Isn't we are proving tht $B$ is inverse of $A$ ? So how can we use $AB(y) = y$ if that is what is needed to proved.

Comment: $B(y)$ is the only solution to the equation $Ax = y$. So, $AB(y)=y$. But that does not mean that $B$ is inverse of $A$. We must verify also that $BA(x) = x$ for all $x$. What I proved above is that $B$ is linear.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $B(y)$ is a unique solution $\mathbf{x}$ of equation $AX=y$.

So, the solution of equation $A(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2) = \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2$ is $B(\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2) = \alpha x_1 + \beta y_2 = \alpha B(y_1) + \beta B(y_2)$.